# I am trying to display indented XML within a MVC3 View, and I cannot get it to work, it just appears non indented?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have been trying to use the XElement, as advised by John Saunders. However My XML is not indented in the Razor View. I must be doing something silly, but I cannot see it.

Controller Code:

```
XElement myXElement = XElement.Load(strMapPath + strFileName);
ViewBag.MyOrigDocXML = myXElement;
return View();
```

Razor Code in View:

```
@if(ViewBag.MyOrigDocXML != null)
{
@ViewBag.MyOrigDocXML.ToString();
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would nest your code inside pre html tags like

```
<link href="~/Content/Prettify/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/Prettify/prettify.js"></script>

<body onload="prettyPrint()">
    <pre class="prettyprint lang-xml">@ViewBag.MyOrigDocXML;</pre>
</body>
```

this will then give you your xml in an indented layout, then add prettify to get xml text highlighted

Comment: So Simple..... :) Thanks. Dare I ask what you do to get highlighting of the text like IE does. I have seen a Javascript utility that does this, and I think it is called "Highlighter", but no nesting.

Comment: In the past I have used Google Prettify (from Nuget - Install-Package Prettify) to highlight the text.  I have updated the answer to include Prettify in the example.